# laravel relationship between 5 tables

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have 5 tables User, Profile, Address,State,City .Need to create relationship between tables.Address has State id , City id and Profile id in the table.Profile has User Id in the table.City has State Id in the table. How to write relationship between table

```php
class City extends Model
{
    public function state() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
    }

    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
    }
}


class State extends Model
{
    public function cities() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }

    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    public function address() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
    }
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}

class Address extends Model
{
    public function profile() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
    }
    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
    public function state() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
    }

}

// users table
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Comment: please explain what problems you face...

Answer (score 0):

Generally your model design is true, i have edited a few parts. Try the codes below.

```
class City extends Model
{
     public function state()  
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
     }

     public function addresses() 
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
     }
}


class State extends Model
{
     public function cities() 
     {
          return $this->hasMany('App\City');
     }

     public function addresses() 
     {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
     }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
     public function addresses() 
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
     }

     public function user() 
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     }
}

class Address extends Model
{
      public function profile() 
      {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
      }

      public function city() 
      {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
      }

      public function state() 
      {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\State');
      }
}

class User extends Model
{
     public function profile()
     {
          return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
     }
}
```

**By the way**, Laravel relationships add default keys according to your method names. If you have problem about it you can find info from official documents. For example:

> $this->belongsTo('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');

Answer (score 0):

as @mustafa.akcoban says...

When you use belongsTo Eloquent will work as follow

```
$this->belongsTo('App\City', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
// foreign_key = is the primary key in the related model, by default 'id' for Eloquent 
// other_key = is the field in the current model that contains the id of the other model, by default othermodelname_id for Eloquent
// For eg. 'App\City', 'id', 'city_id'
```

When you use hasMany Eloquent works as follow

```
$this->hasMany('App\Model', 'currentmodel_id', 'primary_key');
// currentmodel_id = is the field that contains the current model primary key in the related model
// primary_key = is the current primary key model that will be in the other model, by default id for Eloquent
// For eg. 'App\City', 'state_id', 'id'
```

Remember you can or can't use second and third parameter, if something is wrong Laravel dump will tell you what column was not found in the table, and you will can fix.

Please try and practice this, and let me know how it works :)